# Comparison of content_tag and normal htm tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can anyone describe some use cases of content_tag in rails. I mean why should i prefer it over simple syntax of tags. Compare content_tag(:div) over html div tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience I tend to use `content_tag` inside of helper methods (in `app/helpers`). `content_tag` tends to get unwieldily pretty quickly (especially when nesting them w/ blocks) so I only use them for shorter HTML helpers.

`content_tag` is great for dynamically creating things. For example here is a helper method for generating an unordered list w/ items

```
  def ul(items = [], attributes = {}, &block)
    content_tag :ul, attributes do
      yield(items) if block_given?
      [*items].map { |i| content_tag :li, i }.join.html_safe
    end
  end
```

This allows you to do things like

```
ul ['first', 'second', 'third']
```

or even pass a block list

```
ul do |l|
  l << "first"
  l << "second"
  l << "third"
```

Using a helper method here instead of raw HTML makes this code more reusable (DRY) and also allows for flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

Tag helpers are useful when you want to dynamically generate blocks of HTML. For example, see this post I wrote about generating Twitter Bootstrap breadcrumbs: http://www.nicolasgarnil.me/blog/2012/neat-breadcrumbs-with-some-ruby-magic/.

If you are writing static markup you should stick to the HTML tags. If you wan't to wrap the logic to generate a html component like a breadcrumb, nested fields, etc, use tag helpers.